Redux & Redux persist - Handle multiple instances in one redux store (sessionStorage)
At first some basic details about my issue:

A service portal (hosted by other teams)
Exactly one browser tab where users are logged in into this Service Portal
Within the Service Portal, my ReactJS application (with redux, redux persist and redux toolkit) is embedded by other teams (as iFrame and later on as web component)
My ReactJS app can be opened multiple times (1 to n times) by users

Problem: These multiple instances (of my ReactJS app) are opened in one and the same browser tab although my app uses sessionStorage!
Of course this is a problem, as the ReactJS app makes usage of redux & redux persist (with sessionStorage) and sessionStorage exists PER BROWSER TAB. Now the problem of overwriting exists as these multiple instances access one and the same sessionStorage (redux store) as they exactly share one browser tab.
I know that redux is designed to mainly use a single store. But there are ways to implement "instances" kind of I think.
Stumbled upon this: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#custom-context

What I look for is:
Ideas, how to

Manage multiple instances in one and the same redux store dynamically
By using sessionStorage and redux toolkit
Without preconfiguring the amount of contexts staticly

To do so, my idea is to generate a uuidv4 at the very beginning of the app start (to have a uniquish id) and somehow store all the data for this instance within an object in redux for that by using its uuidv4.
But I don't know how to do this in redux toolkit appropriately.
So something like:
{
  "modules": {
    "107af8f5-4240-463b-8a27-1f0354ec078c": {
      "customer": {
        "id": "2948",
        "firstname": "Max",
        "lastname": "Mustermann"
      },
      "isPresentationMode": true,
      "isNavBarOpen": true
    },
    "fb0fde5e-ab4b-4283-bd3f-64d740f92161": {
      "customer": {
        "id": "14567",
        "firstname": "Sara",
        "lastname": "Neufeld"
      },
      "isPresentationMode": true,
      "isNavBarOpen": true
    },
    "458d3667-002a-4eae-a672-57138b94d221": {
      "customer": {
        "id": "9274748",
        "firstname": "Daniel",
        "lastname": "Laudmann"
      },
      "isPresentationMode": true,
      "isNavBarOpen": true
    },
    "fe529de5-4c66-4e64-a55a-2e5a654de360": {
      "customer": {
        "id": "3353",
        "firstname": "Anna",
        "lastname": "Holz"
      },
      "isPresentationMode": true,
      "isNavBarOpen": false
    },
    "6880e4b3-4a37-47b5-8517-6b5d6ef3aa78": {
      "customer": {
        "id": "2213456",
        "firstname": "Theodor",
        "lastname": "Neumann"
      },
      "isPresentationMode": false,
      "isNavBarOpen": false
    }
  }
}

I don't know how to create something like a parent reducer in redux toolkit to do this.
What solutions do you have in mind?

That state seems logical to me. What specifically do you need help with? What specific issue or problem do you face? Please [edit] to clarify.
